# The Nuget package (nupkg) doesn't sync with the project latest changes?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, nuget-spec

I created a Nuget package, I made some changes to the project and added some comments, but after updating the package, those changes didn't apply, and still has the first release. I have the NuGet.exe, the *.nuspec and the *.nupkg files in the same directory of the .csproj file of the project class library. I can't figure out what I'm missing!

Comment: Question is unclear. Are you using this nuget package in a project somewhere, and you find that the package that's being referenced in that project is not the package that contains your update? If so, you may have used the same version number for both packages, and the original package may be cached on your machine. Try running a `nuget locals all -clear` and deleting the `packages` folder from your solution directory.

Comment: I'm creating a NuGet package from a class library. I followed this tutorial 
https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package

Comment: Did you create 2 packages over time with the same name and version? If so, and if the problem is that you can't seem to get the updated package to be present in the project that uses the nuget package, it's because it's in cache.

Comment: I remember I tried, but it doesn't allow the package to have same name and version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show XML comments, I should enable in the project properties> Build> check XML documentation file